# Problem with different type synchronized charts ApexCharts.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, apexcharts

I am using ApexCharts.js to create a graph which should be associated with another graph. There's the feature of sync charts but turns out if used line and bar, it's not working as expected.
Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/moviecrew/eL76yfkr/7/

I have used `group: 'group name'` and `id` to link those 2 charts.

In the fiddle, you can notice how the linked chart doesn't work when we hover on line chart but it works good if hovered on bar chart.

If bar chart is changed to Line, it works as well. but i need it to be bar.

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you

Comment: I seem to be having the same problem with synchronizing a candlestick chart with a bar chart. I suspect it may be a bug worth reporting on the Github issues page.

Comment: @nathanl93 I have reported the bug too in the GitHub issues but they have not responded yet

Answer (score 0):

See [this JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p79ztu8x/) for more detail:

```
type: 'bar'
```

Comment: There is still the same misalignment problem in your example. It becomes much more obvious when you use fewer data points that the first value for a line chart starts at zero on the x-axis, while the first value in the bar chart has a small offset. If you change your tooltips to be shared and have fixed positions so they don't overlap each other, you can also see that the data points in the tooltips don't always come from the same data array indices as one another.